# Trouble combining columns into one vector

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, multiple-columns

I am trying to combine the same named column from n csv sheets into one vector for which I can then ask for the mean of the vector and get one value.

Instead it seems I get a vector of numeric vectors (let's call it Lo). So when I call the mean function on Lo, I get a mean for every of the individual columns.

Below is the code that responds as described in (1)

```r
p <- list.files(getwd(), full.names = TRUE)[1:10] 
Re <- c()

for(i in p) {
  Lo <- read.csv(i, header = TRUE)
  Zo <- na.omit(Lo$sulfate)
  An <- c(Re, Zo)
  print(mean(An)
}
```

I do not get error messages. I should only be getting one mean value, #but instead I get a mean for each sheet's $sulfate column.

```
#[1] 3.880701
#[1] 4.460811
#[1] 4.327613
#[1] 4.214956
#[1] 4.210072
#[1] 4.102132
#[1] 3.820059
#[1] 4.781354
#[1] 3.645644
#[1] 0.6243649
```

Comment: You are printing the mean within the loop. So it will print the mean of item i, and then go to the next item i, print the mean, and then go to the next, and so on. You need to store the intermediate means in a list and then calculate the overall mean outside of the loop, if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not totally sure this is what you're looking for, but something like this?

```
p <- list.files(getwd(), full.names = TRUE)[1:10]
Re <- c()
vector_list <- list()
for(i in p) {
    Lo <- read.csv(i, header = TRUE)
    Zo <- na.omit(Lo$sulfate)
    An <- c(Re, Zo)
    vector_list[[i]] <- An
    }

mean(unlist(vector_list))
```

Comment: It is returning only a single value, but the value is incorrect. It is taking the mean of the mean of each column, rather than combine the columns into one and running the mean on all those values.

Comment: You're welcome, please accept the answer if you're happy with it :)